# Cache memories and memory addresses

Tags: c, caching, memory-address

I have to do one class´s exercise where I have to do some subroutines and then check the cache misses, this is the atachment:

I have to create 2 subroutines where s1 is the capacity of my L1 cache 32kb and b1 is the line witdh 64 bytes.

```
subroutine A: increment all bytes of a memory buffer containing 2*s1 bytes 
in the order of increasing memory addresses;

subroutine B: increment each b1-th byte of a memory buffer containing 2*s1
 bytes in the order of increasing memory addresses;
```

For subroutine A I think I just have to do:

```
char buffer[2*s1];  
printf...
buffer++;
printf...
```

both printf will show:

```
buffer[0]= 0x7fff36769fe0 buffer[1]= 0x7fff36769fe1 
buffer[0]= 0x7fff36769fe1 buffer[1]= 0x7fff36769fe2
```

All bytes would be increassed,so, I think that it is correct,and for subroutine B, I have no idea...So, I would like to have some help for subroutine B.

It would be nice if someone can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that is right even for A. You are only incrementing the **pointer** to the buffer. You need to increment the **contents** of the buffer. That is, you need to do something like; `(*buffer)++; buffer++;` And you need to do it in a loop so that it's done for **all** bytes in the buffer. Also, probably clearer/simpler to use array subscripts rather than pointer aritmetic.

Comment: ... and FWIW, the second exercise is similar to the first, except that rather than incrementing *every* byte you'll only be incrementing the bytes at `array[b1]`, `array[b1 * 2]`, `array[b1 * 3]`, ...

Comment: it's strange that, the key part of this exercise is to time the program, examine cache miss rate, and explain them, but you are struggling at coding it.

Comment: Please avoid wholly irrelevant observations. It adds nothing to the question, much less any answer, nor does it request additional clarification from the questioner. The questioner is here for help, not to be ridiculed.

Answer (score 0):

These exercises only makes sense as a lesson in optimisation. Unfortunately, they're not quite hitting the figurative head of the nail.

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

That's a famous quote, along-side its context, from perhaps the most reputable teacher we can agree upon in this field: Donald Knuth. Following on from this exercise, your professor will probably introduce you to *profilers* by walking you through profiling your *unoptimised* code.

What can we hope to improve if we apply manual optimisations as though the compiler performs none, and only later enable the compilers automatic optimisations? Perhaps the compiler might automatically perform the same optimisations (or better optimisations) we manually perform, but in a miniscule fraction of the time.

There's a marketing/planning strategy to consider behind those figures in that quote. In the commercial world or even as a hobbyist, you will have spent the 97% of your time up front developing *and testing* a program that solves the *actual problem*. Notice the emphasis on *actual problem*. You won't be writing and testing programs for the purpose of observing cache behaviours. You'll be writing and testing programs to solve *real life problems*.

Once you've written and tested the entire program thoroughly you'll know whether or not it *feels* fast enough (e.g. you'll probably be told by your clients/employers to optimise it). If it *feels* fast enough, you won't optimise it, even if there are cache misses everywhere; you won't even know there are cache misses. If it *feels* too slow, however, you'll want use a profiler on your *fully optimised* code to determine where the most significant bottleneck is, and spend roughly 3% of your time on that bottleneck...

It is possible to program optimistically, but that's not an exercise in observation like these exercises; it's an exercise in planning and factoring. One guideline is to *avoid repeating yourself*, which is what I've done with the code below. By **determining the common behaviours** between the two exercises (e.g. both loop from low indexes to high indexes, incrementing each element by 1) I've reduced two loops to one, and avoided repeating myself at the same time. Factor your programs to avoid as much repetition as possible and your code will be smaller, resulting in less testing, maintenance and of course *less repeated keystrokes*. *Most* of the optimisation is an optimisation of *our* time, not of the computers time! It just so happens that we are also optimising the computer time by making our code smaller.

```
void increment_every(char *buffer, size_t multiple, size_t maximum) {
    while (maximum > multiple) {
        buffer[0]++;
        buffer  += multiple;
        maximum -= multiple;
    }
}
```

You should be able to solve both of these problems in terms of this function. For example:

```
#define S1 32768 /* 32KB */
#define B1 64    /* 64 B */

int main(void) {
    char buffer[2 * S1] = { 0 };

    increment_every(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer);  // subroutine A

    if (B1 < S1) {                              // subroutine B
        increment_every(buffer + B1, B1, sizeof buffer - B1);
    }
}
```

This is assuming `S1` and `B1` are fixed values that don't come from a file or an interactive device. Such an assumption causes the compiler to be quite aggressive with optimisation. In fact, this program will probably be optimised to `int main(void) { }` because there's no *observable behaviour*; there's no input from or output to any files or interactive devices *anywhere* in this program! Hopefully, now, you'll see a few true lessons behind your next lesson:

- **Write code optimally rather than write optimal code**. e.g. Avoid repeating yourself.
- **Profile your code only when it *feels* too slow**. e.g. Optimise only after you've written and tested the entire program.

Comment: The purpose of this exercise is simply to demonstrate the effect of cache: cache will get the data in chunk of a cache line, it doesn't matter you use the each whole line or a byte of each line.

Comment: @user3528438 This exercise is ineffective at describing the mechanisms of caching because it doesn't actually implement or describe the mechanisms of caching. The OP mentioned "cache misses", which makes it an exercise in observing potentials for optimisation.

Comment: after create the subroutines, tje purpose of the program, is, for each subroutine, determine average time of a byte access, as well as the achieved bandwidth in MB/s.
But I asked also the other becuase I had doubts too.

Thank you undefined behaviour.